# How does sql server FCI respond to failure?

Tags: sql-server, clustering, windows-server, high-availability, failover

Taking windows role default settings - (n-1) failovers ok within 6 hrs , where n=# of nodes, if nodes = 2, 1 failover within 6 hrs is allowed.

Taking resource default settings - Within 15mins period, 1 restart is allowed on the same node, else failover, RetryPeriodOnFailure is 1 hr

Taking a example of a simple 2 node cluster (node1 & Node2), single sqlFCI (sql), say sql is on node 1 at 9AM.

9AM - sql fails - attempts to restart on Node1 - fails - failsover to Node2 - attempts to restart on Node2 - fails - stays failed.

Now where I am confused is, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/947712/failover-cluster-resource-recovery-behavior-in-windows-server-2008 , "If there is no intervention and the resource remains in the failed state for 60 minutes, Windows Server tries to bring the resource online again. "

So, according to above, after 60mins, say sometime after 10AM - Does sql try a cycle again :

Attempts sql restart on Node2 - fails - (but cannot failover as 6hrs have not passed)

11AM- Attempts sql restart on Node2 - fails - (but cannot failover as 6hrs have not passed)

12PM - Attempts sql restart on Node2 - fails - (but cannot failover as 6hrs have not passed)

1PM - Attempts sql restart on Node2 - fails - (but cannot failover as 6hrs have not passed)

2PM - Attempts sql restart on Node2 - fails - (but cannot failover as 6hrs have not passed)

3PM - Attempts sql restart on Node2 - fails - failsover to node1 as 6 hrs have passed, tries coming online there , and so on.. is this how it happens? Thanks.

Comment: Which windows version are you referring here?

Comment: Win 08/16 Server